# Datagenerator to feed smalls BatchDataset to train model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm building a Datagenerator to loads a set of data in stored files (dataframes), transform them into time series using `tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array`  to train a model.

This is what I have build by using this [article](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly):

```
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, df_index, train_mean, train_std, seq_len=128, batch_size=32, shuffle=False):
        'Initialization'
        self.df_index   = df_index
        self.data_index = list(df_index.index)
        self.train_mean = train_mean
        self.train_std  = train_std
        self.seq_len    = seq_len
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle    = shuffle

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int((self.df_index.length.cumsum().iloc[-1] - seq_len) // batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, ds_index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
                # Generate data
        file_id = self.data_index[ds_index]
        data_obj = joblib.load(f"{data_path}{data_prefix}_{file_id}.pkl")
        X_norm = (data_obj.data_var - self.train_mean) / self.train_std
        data_ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(X_norm[:-self.seq_len],
                                                       data_obj.targets[self.seq_len:],
                                                       batch_size=self.batch_size,
                                                       sequence_length=self.seq_len,
                                                       shuffle=self.shuffle)
        return data_ds

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        random.shuffle(self.data_index)
```

**The origin**:
I'm creating this generator because I want to use a GPU to train my model. As `tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array`loads the entire dataset into memory (which is huge) I had to split it into parts.

**My problem**:
`__getitem__` is returning a `BatchDataset` object while the fit model is expecting the batch.

I was thinking to create a loop that iterates on the Dataset and delivers the batches but I don't know how (Considering that after ending one I have to load the next file an create the next Dataset)... any advice?

Comment: The article you're using is quite outdated. I would advise against using `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` entirely. Use the `tf.data` API instead. See this guide about how it interacts with keras: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#using_tfdata_with_tfkeras

Comment: oh, thanks.
my issue is that I want to use GPU to do the training and the dataset is huge to fit in memory.
As timeseries_dataset_from_array does some kind of data preparation but loads the entire datframe in memory I'm looking for ways to do it in chunks.
I'll take a look to the doc you send!
Thanks again!